# Laptop connected to external monitor results in desktop overflow

Tags: windows-7, laptop, resolution, hdmi, external-display

I have a laptop (MSi FX600) connected to an external monitor (Toshiba 19AV500U) with the screen resolution set to the monitors recommended setting of 1440x900. The problem is the desktop is overflowing the display, meaning all edges of the desktop are cut off, so I cannot see the close, minimize buttons on the top and I only see half of the taskbar at the bottom.

I have tried many different resolutions but none of them solve the problem. I have had this same problem when connecting to other external monitors in the past, but not all of them, it seems to be fairly random. I have tried to find a way to manually adjust the resolution but I cannot see a way to do this in my settings. All windows updates are up to date, I am connecting through an HDMI cable and I have it set to display only on the external monitor and not extended desktop.

Comment: *"The problem is the desktop is overflowing the display"* -- The proper name for this condition is **overscan**. Overscan is common when displaying computer images on a TV or HDTV or video monitor. Overscan should not occur if you were using a computer monitor.  The Toshiba 19AV500U is a HDTV and is not a computer monitor, hence it's not surprising that it has overscan. *"it seems to be fairly random."* -- No it's not random; you're calling everything a "monitor" and failing to make the distinction between HDTVs and computer monitors.

Comment: @sawdust Thank you for the information regarding overscan and why it is overscanning in my situation. I did know that the Toshiba is a TV...I mean, how could I not?...I was referring to it as a monitor because that's what I was using it for as opposed to a TV. Regardless, that was my error and thank you for clarifying it for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the "monitor" you are connecting to is really a TV. It is not correctly reporting it's native video size back to the PC.

Depending on the capabilities of the monitor, you need to set the resolution to one of the native HDTV settings. Can't remember horizontal resolutions off the top of my head but you want one that has a vertical resolution of 1080 (best) or 720.